# Resize app automatically depending on screen size in swift

Tags: swift, autolayout

I just started making an app, and I have done a lot but I was not working with auto-layout. My whole app is in landscape mode, and I want it to work on all iPhone's. I now designed it for the iPhone 5, but when I open it on iPhone 6, there is a lot of whitespace. Is there a button to automatically resize everything? Or must I add auto layout and do every designing bit again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you're probably going to have to layout everything again with auto-layout. A way to expedite your process would be converting the storyboard to auto-layout and then selecting "Reset to Suggested Constraints". You can access this option by pressing the small triangle icon in the bottom left.

[image]

Despite this, you probably **will** need to update a lot of the constraints manually. But this should give you a step in the right direction.

Comment: When I click on "Use Auto Layout" it is loading and after a few seconds I see a lock in the middle of my screen. How do I turn on auto layout?

Comment: Did you also check the "Use Size Classes" box?

Comment: When I clicked on size classes, everything worked. We'll, auto layout is on, but now my whole app looks funny hehe. I am gonna fix that. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Size Classes? Or Stack Views?

Size classes:
Apple documentation @   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html

[image: Size Classes]

Apple documentation on Stack Views @
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH11-SW1

A good tutorial on "Stack Views":
https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views